# OCaml : as keyword in pattern matching behaving strangely

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

Let's say I write this code :

```
# type t = A of int * int
  let f = function A (i1, i2) -> print_int i1;;
type t = A of int * int
val f : t -> unit = <fun>
```

Perfect, it works.

Now, let's say I have this wonderful function :

```
# let print_couple (i1, i2) = print_int i1; print_int i2;;
val print_couple : int * int -> unit = <fun>
```

So, as you expect, I'd like to write the following

```
# let f = function A (_ as c) -> print_couple c;;
```

Well, I can't

```
Error: The constructor A expects 2 argument(s),
       but is applied here to 1 argument(s)
```

I wondered, is it because of the `_` or the parenthesis (I seriously had doubts about that but I wanted to be exhaustive) ?

```
# let f = function A _ -> failwith "Fight me"
  let g = function A (_) -> failwith "1o1";;
val f : t -> 'a = <fun>
val g : t -> 'a = <fun>
```

No, it isn't...

Oh, maybe I have to show the compiler I know I have two arguments :

```
# let f = function A ((_, _) as c) -> print_couple c;;
Error: The constructor A expects 2 argument(s), 
       but is applied here to 1 argument(s)
```

But... If I write

```
# let f = function A (_, _) -> failwith "Puppey style";;
```

It works. Then why, since the compiler knows that I'm expecting a couple and I'm even trying to give it to him it keeps failing ? Is it that by writing `A (_ as c)` I'm naming, no matter what, the first argument ? It's strange, isn't it ?

I mean, if I write

```
# let rec f = function
    | [] -> ()
    | hd :: tl -> print_couple hd; f tl;;
val f : (int * int) list -> unit = <fun>
```

The compiler won't bother me about this list being an association list or an integer list ? Then is it strange from me to expect the same behaviour from

```
 # match a with
    | A c | A (_ as c) | A ((_, _) as c) -> ()
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a quirk of OCaml that a constructor like your definition of `A` takes what syntactically looks like a pair, but is not a pair.

```
# type t = A of int * int;;
type t = A of int * int
# A (3, 4);;
- : t = A (3, 4)
# let z = (3, 4) in A z;;
Error: The constructor A expects 2 argument(s),
       but is applied here to 1 argument(s)
```

If you define the constructor as actually taking a pair, you can supply a pair:

```
# type u = B of (int * int);;
type u = B of (int * int)
# B (3, 4);;
- : u = B (3, 4)
# let z = (3, 4) in B z;;
- : u = B (3, 4)
```

This is somewhat confusing, but it's just the way OCaml works. You need to supply specifically parenthesized arguments to a constructor like `A`.

It's also a little surprising that you don't need to supply explicit parentheses when matching against `_`:

```
# let A _ = A (4, 5);;
#
```

(This is only useful as part of a larger pattern, of course.)

Comment: About your edit, isn't it strange, indeed ? Because if I expect two parameters I would expect (_, _). I guess it's just a syntactic sugar because you often want to match only the constructor without taking in account the parameters but you can't allow something like (_ as c) because "c" wouldn't be a pair.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, when you declare `A of int * int`, `A` expects two `int` arguments and not a single argument consisting in a pair of `int`. `_` is a placeholder for only one argument, hence the error message you see when you write `A (_ as c)` (or `A _`). There is no way (short of using dark magic I won't describe here) to somehow implicitely transform the two arguments of `A` into a pair: you have to resort to `match x with A (x,y) -> x,y`.

An alternative is to declare your constructor so that it takes a pair, like in the code below. Be aware that this is less efficient though (you need two indirections to access the arguments of `A`, one to retrieve the couple, and one to retrieve its components):

```
type t = A of (int * int)
let print_couple (i1, i2) = print_int i1; print_int i2
let f = function A c -> print_couple c
```

Comment: Upvote but sadly I can't accept two answers. Thanks for the efficiency matter. ;-)