# Binding name while matching sum type in OCaml

Tags: types, ocaml

In OCaml, is it possible to bind a name to the guts of a data constructor while pattern matching? As an illustrative example, suppose I have the following OCaml program:

```
type t = A of int * int | B of int * int

let sum_pair (a, b) = a + b

let f x = match x with
  | A (a1, a2) -> sum_pair (a1, a2)
  | B (_, b) -> b

let _ = Printf.printf "%d\n" (f (A (1, 2)))
```

This compiles, but it's rather annoying that I need to reconstruct the tuple `(a1, a2)` after matching to pass it to `sum_pair`! Instead, I want to be able to write

```
let f x = match x with
  | A (_ as pair) -> sum_pair pair
  | B (_, b) -> b
```

but this fails with "Error: The constructor A expects 2 argument(s), but is applied here to 1 argument(s)." Writing

```
let f x = match x with
  | A _ as pair -> sum_pair pair
  | B (_, b) -> b
```

is no better, as this binds `pair` to the whole value, rather than the pair within. (This also fails to compile, as you would expect: "This expression has type t but an expression was expected of type int * int.")

Comment: This is what BDFL is saying: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/ml-archives/caml-list/1997/01/f8f69190c168ae796d3a16ed0e0dfa92.en.html

Comment: Also, as a side comment, I would like to notice, that the language resists you for a good reason. It actually is trying to tell you, that you're doing something wrong. There is no good reason to create a curried function, as every time you apply it, a new pair should be created. So, you `sum_pair` has a terrible overhead. The better version should be: `| A (x,y) -> sum_pair x y`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make this work if you define the type this way:

```
type t = A of (int * int) | B of (int * int)
```

What this means is that the constructor A actually takes *one* argument that's a pair. In your original definition it takes two int arguments that are not a pair, and there's no way around this.

```
# type t = A of (int * int) | B of (int * int);;
type t = A of (int * int) | B of (int * int)

# let sum_pair (a, b) = a + b 

  let f x = match x with
  | A p -> sum_pair p
  | B (_, b) -> b
  ;;
val sum_pair : int * int -> int = <fun>
val f : t -> int = <fun>

# f (A (5, 7));;
- : int = 12
```

This is a tricky point of OCaml syntax. Here is another recent discussion: ['as' Keyword in Pattern Matching Behaving Strangely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002575/ocaml-as-keyword-in-pattern-matching-behaving-strangely).

Comment: Generally I don't dislike OCaml syntax but this is just ugly. OP's A constructor is used with exactly the same syntax as the one in this answer but they have different types. Why can't we have function syntax for constructors? Is it only so they cannot be curried?

Comment: We can have the function syntax, see `[@@deriving variants]`.